Ag-Grid valueFormatter in defaultColDefs - does not work
This is probably the last obstacle in development process, so any kind of help be much appreciated, as soon as possible.
I am using Ag-Grid to display different columns. Columns are fully dynamic - meaning I don't know how many of them, or what type it will be.
I need to format all numbers to be shown like this:
10,123,456.78
Also, value, has to stay a number, in order to use filter with intended options (Less, Greater, Between, etc.)
What I tried:
defaultColDef: ColDef = {
  flex: 1,
  filter: true,
  editable: true,
  floatingFilter: true,
  valueFormatter: (params) => {
    return typeof params.value === 'number' ? params.value.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'decimal' }) : params.value;
  }
  
 }


did you find a solution? I experience similar behavior

Hello, yes. You will have to define custom function in separate script and then call it in app-component.ts.
You will have to try Parse each value.
